# Show of a guy from a human evolved future who travels back to 20th century to find other time traveler and save humanity

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, evolution

I don't remember too many details. It was a late 80s early 90's tv show. I watched dubbed to Spanish, but I think it may have been American(?).

The guy travels to the 20th century to trap someone(?) and save humanity. I think he comes from 23-25th centuries and human bodies have evolved, making them have an increased heart bit rate and making them more efficient and faster.

He is helped but a woman (police?) People are not aware of time travel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is  [***Time Trax***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Trax).

> In the year 2193, over a hundred criminals become fugitives of law enforcement by traveling back in time two hundred years to a parallel Universe, using a time machine called Trax. Darien Lambert is a police detective of that period who is sent back to 1993 in order to apprehend as many of the fugitives as possible
>
> He [Darien Lambert] is assisted by the Specified Encapsulated Limitless Memory Archive,
> or SELMA, an extremely small but very powerful computer (described as
> equivalent to a mainframe) disguised for the mission as a credit card;
> SELMA communicates through a holographic interface which takes the
> visual form of a prim young woman.
>
> As a child of his time, he has abilities superior to those of 20th-century humans: IQ 204, a speed memorization rate of 1.2 pages per second, a top speed of 8.6 seconds for 100m, a heartbeat of 35 beats per minute and a life expectancy of 120 years

Comment: Yes! Time Thank you so much. This was making me crazy!